# Is there a way to store a variadic template of a specific type C++

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

Lets say I have the following scenario where I am printing templates of type `std::size_t`.

```cpp
template<std::size_t st>
void print_sizes(){
    std::cout << st << std::endl;
}

template<std::size_t st, std::size_t M, std::size_t... Rest>
void print_sizes(){
    std::cout << st << std::endl;
}

int main(){
    print_sizes<10, 12, 3>();
}
```

The above is entirely valid. However, I was wondering if there was a way to store the `10,12,3` variadic template like the following:

```cpp
template<std::size_t st>
void print_sizes(){
    std::cout << st << std::endl;
}

template<std::size_t st, std::size_t M, std::size_t... Rest>
void print_sizes(){
    std::cout << st << std::endl;
    print_sizes<M, Rest...>();
}

using example = 10, 12, 3;
int main(){
    print_sizes<example>();
}
```

Obviously, that doesn't work and throws an error. Is there a way to do something like this though?

Comment: This is trivial. Wrap them into a type: `template<std::size_t...> class wrapper {}; using example = wrapper<10, 12, 3>;`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't easily store the `10, 12, 3` parameter pack itself, but you can store a template instantiated over those parameters:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<std::size_t st>
void print_sizes(){std::cout<<st<<std::endl;}

template<std::size_t st, std::size_t M, std::size_t... Rest>
void print_sizes(){
    std::cout<<st<<std::endl;
    print_sizes<M, Rest...>();
}

int main(){
    auto f = print_sizes<10, 12, 3>; // save instantiated template

    f();                             // invoke it.
    return 0;
}
```

Note that if you can use C++17 or newer, you probably want to use a fold expression instead of the variadic template.

Since you seem to want a compile-time list of things of one type, you might prefer an initializer list:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

void print_sizes(std::initializer_list<std::size_t> numbers) { 
    for (auto num : numbers)
        std::cout << num << "\n";
}

int main() { 
    print_sizes({10, 12, 3});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think [`std::integer_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) (since C++14) and [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) (since C++17) might be what you are looking for:

[Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ebea67f162b6bb4)

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, T... ints>
void print_sequence(std::integer_sequence<T, ints...> seq) {
  ((std::cout << ints << std::endl), ...);
}

constexpr auto seq = std::integer_sequence<size_t, 10, 12, 3>{};

int main() { print_sequence(seq); }
```

Comment: These are good solutions, but the question is tagged C++11, so the answer should at least contain an alternative that works in C++11 as well.